# Problem executing Mean Shift Segmentation: could not open the output layers

Tags: qgis, sextante, orfeo-toolbox, mean-shift

I have a problem executing the Mean Shift Segmentation in QGIS with Orfeo Toolbox. I put all the parameter to execute and then, nearly 5s after appear the message that SEXTANTE could not open the output layers.

Answer (score 2):

What parameters did you try for the segmentation?

The OTB segmentation module got 2 modes, a raster mode which outputs a image of label and a vector mode which works on larger image and include a tilling scheme. This last mode output the segmentation results in vector mode.

Have a look to this post which describe the application:

http://blog.orfeo-toolbox.org/preview/coming-next-large-scale-segmentation

Hope it helps